# Using database objects in base.html

Tags: python, django

When I have full set of model+view+url+template then it goes fine,
but I want to try a top menu with my products' categories without specific given url. I want it to be in menu child template(?) whose parent is `base.html`.
(I want it to be global within my website, yes)

here are my codes:

**models.py**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def parents(self):
        return self.parent

    def tree(self):
        return f"{self.parent} | {self.name}"
```

**views.py**

```
class CategoryView(ListView):
    model = Category
    template_name = 'category_list.html'
    queryset = model.objects.all()
    context_object_name = 'categories'
```

**base.html**

```
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        {% include 'navbar.html' %}
        {% include 'category_list.html' %}
        {% block content_body %}{% endblock %}
        {% include 'footer.html' %}
    </div>
</body>
```

**category_list.html**

```
<div class="row">
    {% for cat in categories %}
        <div class="col-1">
            {{ cat.name }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('category/', CategoryView.as_view(), name='category'),
]
```

If I visit the url `127.0.0.1/category`, these categories show up, but not in any other pages. So it's not globally showing in every pages of my website.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean with if you give it a *specific* url; every view needs a url to work with, either a pattern or a static url that django searchs for and runs the view on match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using context processors. Create a file named context_processors.py in you app directory. In this file, define your categories as the following :

```
def categories(request):
from yourapp.models import Category
categories = Category.objects.all()

return {
    'categories ': categories ,  # Add 'categories ' to the context
}
```

then edit your settings.py :

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    ...
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            ...
            'yourapp.context_processors.categories',
        ]
    }
}
```

]

then you can access it like this for example :

```
{% for c in categories %}
 {{ c.attribute_you_want_to_show }}
{% endfor %}
```